# compatiblity with Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 (on tablet)

Tags: wifi, linux-kernel, drivers, proprietary-drivers, tablet

I hold a [Dell Venue Pro 11 7130](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Venue-11-Pro-7130-Tablet-Review-Update.132423.0.html)  with the following integrated network adapter:
Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7260.
My aim is using Linux in live mode on it.

Most of the distros I've being running so far do work but they don't recognize it. They come with different kernel (older and newer), in particular the distros which did run on my tablet are the following:

- Backbox 4.4
- Fedora 23
- Kali linux 2.0
- Kali linux light 2.0
- Linuxmint 17.3 Cinnamon
- Lubuntu 15.10
- Tails 1.8.1
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Ubuntu 15.10
- Ubuntu 15.10 mate

It seems that the wireless adapter is not even recognized at all (by giving the `ifconfig` , `ifconfig-a` , `lspci` , `iwconfig` on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS  I didn't obtain it).

Since I've read that some laptops coming with the same adapter didn't report so many issues than mine, I wonder if this depends on the adapter only, so I would like to ask:

according to your experience, does the issue depend on the Intel adapter only or is it not excludible that it may depend on some other hardware features related to the specific device in use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you are lacking (non-free) firmware for the module. Try to determine what package you need (depends on distro). On debian stretch it would be `firmware-iwlwifi`. On debian jessie it might be `firmware-linux-nonfree`.

If installing the respective firmware package does not solve the problem, what is the output of `lspci`? Can you also post the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`?

Comment: can I determine what package I do need even without having my tablet connected to the internet?

Comment: You should be able to google it on another PC. Then grab the package (in whatever format required), transfer it to the tablet wire USB and install (command depends on your distro). The output of `lspci` and `dmesg | grep iwl` would help very much to find out if missing firmware is actually the problem.

Comment: The `lspci` command only shows me details about the following components (no wireless adapter):

_host bridge, 
VGA compatible controller , 
Audio device ,
USB controller ,
Communication controller ,
Audio device , 
PCI bridge , 
ISA bridge , 
SATA controller , 
SMBus ,
SD host controller ._

The `dmesg | grep iwl` gives me no output.